# NodeJS: Automatic login after register a user

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I'm trying to login a user after register, but I get the following error:

[image: error: failed to serialize user into session]

Here is my register's method:

```
register(req, res, next) {

    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        req.flash('errors', errors.array({
            onlyFirstError: true
        }));
        res.redirect('back');
    } else {

        const SQL = `SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ${pool.escape(req.body.email)}`;

        pool.query(SQL, (err, result) => {
            if (result.length !== 0) {
                req.flash('error_message', 'El email ofrecido ya está registrado. Vuelva a intentarlo.');
                res.redirect('back');
            } else {
                const sql = 'INSERT INTO contact_app.users (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';

                pool.query(sql, [req.body.username, req.body.email, Hash.encryptPass(req.body.password)],
                    (err) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error(err);
                        } else {
                            console.log('User registered correctly.');
                        }
                    });

                initPassport();

                req.login([req.body.email, req.body.password], (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return next(err);
                    } else {
                        res.redirect('/perfil');
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I thank there is an error in my passport.js file, but when I want to login normally, it works perfectly. Here is my passport.js:

```
import passport from 'passport';
import { Strategy } from 'passport-local';
import pool from '../database/db';
import bcrypt from '../lib/bcrypt';

const initPassport = () => passport.use('local', new Strategy({

    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',


}, (username, password, done) => {
    const sql = 'SELECT * FROM users where email = ?';
    pool.query(sql, [username], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {

            if (result.length > 0) {
                const user = result[0];
                const validPassword = bcrypt.matchPass(password, user.password);

                if (validPassword) {
                    return done(null, user);
                } else {
                    return done(null, false);
                }

            } else {
                return done(null, false);
            }

        }
    });
}));

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    return done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', [id], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            if (result.length > 0) {
                return done(null, result[0]);
            } else {
                return done(null, false);
            }
        }
    });
});

export default initPassport;
```

I'm not sure if in the req.login method I must put the entire user that I have registered, or only the email and password to match with passport fields.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `query()` async? Shouldn't the call to `initPassport()` be inside the callback?

Comment: I think `query()` is not async, and I don´t understand you very well with the initPassport. Is not correct by this way?

Comment: I'm assuming from your code you're using mySql for nodejs and I'm not expert in that. But I see in your `register()` function you're inserting user data into `contact_app.users` by calling `pool.query`. I assume the callback function passed to `query()` gets fired _once the query has finished_. But `initPassport()` is called outside that callback. So potentially you're trying to retrieve the user _before_ the insertion is done. Just guessing here.

Comment: So I should put `initPassport()` inside of pool.query to set in inside the callback?